# Send a c++ std::vector<bool> via mpi

Tags: c++, boolean, mpi

I know that the storage of a `std::vector<bool>` [is not necessarily an array of bools](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector-bool/) .

If I want to send receive int data stored in a `std::vector<int>`, I would use `MPI_Send(vect.data(),num_of_ints,MPI_INT,dest_rk,tag,comm)`.

How should I use `MPI_Send` to send a `std::vector<bool>` ? In particular :

- Can / should I use `vect.data()` as the pointer to buffer ?
- What MPI type should I give ? Somehow, I feel like `MPI_CXX_BOOL` does not apply (see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57598517/how-to-send-boolean-datatype-through-mpi-c))
- What number of elements should I give ? (related to the previous point)

Comment: check [this answer regarding serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51230764/serialization-deserialization-of-a-vector-of-integers-in-c)

Comment: i would not use a `std::vector<bool>` in this case, because strictly speaking it is not a vector of `bool`s. `std::vector<char>` or a vector of `struct Bool { bool x;};` are possible alternatives

Comment: You can also look into using `boost::vector<bool>` which is the standard vector<T> where T=bool.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::vector<bool>` [specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool) does not have the `data()` member function. The underlying storage scheme [is not specified](http://eel.is/c++draft/vector.bool#3) by the standard:

> There is no requirement that the data be stored as a contiguous allocation of `bool` values. A space-optimized representation of bits is recommended instead.

The only reasonable option to send `std::vector<bool>` is to copy it into a vector of `char` (or some similar type like `std::int8_t`), and then send that vector. A better option might be to avoid `std::vector<bool>` in your code from the very beginning.