# Saving a Class (with Vector member) as Binary File in C++

Tags: c++, vector, binary, file-handling

I'm trying to save and load a class `Student` using binary files. This is how the classes are:

```
class Student{
    char name[100];
    int regno;
    vector<Subjects> subjects;
};

class Subjects{
    char initial;
    int id;
};
```

I'm saving and loading this way:

```
void saveFile(){
    fstream f1;
    f1.open("data.bin", ios::out | ios::binary);
    f1.write((char*)&student, sizeof(Student));
    f1.close();
}

void loadFile(){
    fstream f1;
    f1.open("data.bin", ios::in | ios::binary);
    f1.read((char*)&student, sizeof(Student));
    f1.close();
}
```

Nothing fancy as you can see with the saving and loading, but I tested this through print statements, and it's the vector component causing a crash when running it in the terminal `(cmd.exe)`.

Comment: You can't write non-[pod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146452/what-are-pod-types-in-c) classes to a file like that

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51230764/serialization-deserialization-of-a-vector-of-integers-in-c) might be interesting

Comment: And while you're at it: Use `std::string Foo` instead of `char Foo[some_size]`.

Comment: Because `class Student` is not a  POD object (https://stackoverflow.com/a/146454/3421515). It is better to prefer serialization/deserialization library. Such as https://github.com/USCiLab/cereal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't simply save and load the object unless you serialze the `Student` object before saving it to file.

**Rationale:**

class `Student` is not a POD type. `std::vector<Subjects>` in your `Student` class simply holds a pointer to the underlying memory which holds `Subjects`, since `vector` uses heap to hold its contents. When you save the object to a file, you simply save the pointer along with the `Student` object, but not the actual data. Therefore when you try to recreate the same object from the saved binary data, you simply have access to a memory address not the actual content.

In C++ world, `boost::serialization`, `Protocol buffers` and `cereal` are most known (**but not limited to**) serialization libraries to achieve what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

`std::vector` is not a [POD type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146452/what-are-pod-types-in-c).

`std::vector` allocated dynamic memory and stores pointer somewhere internally. When you write it to file, you just write a header to that dynamic memory, which is `std::vector`. When you read it again, it is not a valid pointer anymore, and you get crash.